# Creating canvas for image data and then clearing it?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I was wondering if there is a way to release a canvas and its image data once you no longer need it ?

An example of what I am doing is shown here:

```
img = new Image();
img.src = "test.png";
img.onload = function() {
  var c = document.createElement('canvas'), d, img = this;
  if( c.getContext) {
    c.width = img.width;
    c.height = img.height;
    c = c.getContext("2d");
    c.drawImage(img,0,0);
    d = c.getImageData(0,0,img.width,img.height);
    img.getPixel = function(x,y) {
      return d.slice((y*img.width+x)*4,4);
    };
  }
  else {
    // canvas not supported, fall back
    img.getPixel = function(x,y) {return [0,0,0,0];}
  }
};
```

Once i got the result i want to remove the canvas and imageData that is currently loaded in order to free up some memory.. is there a simple way to remove the temporary canvas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update

So, this is actually something I needed to investigate more thoroughly for a personal project of my own, so I did some testing.

It appears (at least in Chrome) that if you are just creating canvases and getting data URLs, but not actually setting it to an Image element, you're fine and it will garbage collect. This means that your example should garbage collect on it's own.

It is when you get a data URL and assign that to an Image element when things go pear-shaped (most likely due to how browsers handle images).

---

Once all references to that canvas are gone, it will naturally garbage collect itself. So, just make sure you don't have any variables referencing it in a scope which doesn't close.

It looks like with what you are doing, the canvas should disappear.

... or at least that's how it should work.

In reality, it looks like most browsers don't release these from memory until the whole page is unloaded which is problematic (and seems to be quite a few tracking this issue for both Firefox and Chrome, at least).

In the mean time, the most pertinent way to deal with it would be to make the canvas a global (or better yet, tuck it away in some kind of nice manager), so you can then reuse the same canvas over and over. Not ideal, but it'll at least do the trick since you won't be using quite as much memory.